# Using AWS Lambda to Calculate Latencies Between Messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a service that emits messages of two types:

```
Type_1 / Type_2 
(a unique Type_2 always follows a Type_1)
```

I've been thinking about using AWS Lambda to emit metrics on the latency between receiving `Type_1` messages and their corresponding `Type_2` messages that follow (they're 1:1). For example:

```
1. Type_1 arrives
2. Type_2's corresponding Type_2 arrives
3. Lambda (Type_2.timestamp - Type_1.timestamp) = latency between the messages.
```

Is there any simple way to do this in Lambdas? I'm guessing I'll need to cache all of the `Type_1` messages and then grab/diff them as their sister `Type_2` messages come through.

My use case is essentially that if a `Type_2` takes too long (aka over 1 second) to follow its sister message, I'd like to emit some metrics on it.

Comment: Do you mean Cloudwatch metrics? Why not store the results into a DynamoDB table with their timestamps?

Comment: The idea is to emit realtime alarms - but yes I'll be storing the data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to achieve this would be writing the `timestamp` of `Type_1` under an id on S3 (e.g. `s3://bucket-name/id/type_1.timestamp`) and have the `Type_2` function download the file from S3, calculate the delta and decide on any further work based on the timestamps difference.

Comment: Will this work in real time as the messages are processed in Lambda? Or would this be 'after the fact'? What I mean is, is S3 just used as a cache for the Type_1's?

Comment: @Kris I'm not 100% sure I get what you mean. But yes, the idea is to have lambda to use S3 as a key value store/cache. Does every type event has a unique id? Can you please update your answer with a more detailed example? That would also help :)

Comment: Yes, every message has a unique ID associated with it. So, I can query for the corresponding messages rather easily. Just wondering - why S3 over Dynamo or RDS?

Comment: @Kris S3 is mainly very very cheap and would potentially cost a very tiny fraction vs DynamoDB or RDS (you will be charged for every call and data, a true pay as you go model). The only caveat I can think of is S3 eventual consistency but in your case it won't be a problem since you are writing a new file on every new `Type_1` event, you can find more here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel ... BTW careful with which region your will create that cache bucket in US-Standard doesn't support Read-After-Write according to a blog post

Comment: From the S3 FAQ page: Amazon S3 buckets in all Regions provide read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects and eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES.

Comment: Got ya, that should work. Thanks for putting in the time to pass the information along - I definitely appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

*I am assuming you want to do your own metrics and alarms instead of using Cloudwatch.*

My solution would be this:

1. Lambda checks message type.
2. If Type 1, store it in DB (e.g. DynamoDB, RDS, etc) with a timestamp.
3. If Type 2, query the timestamp of its corresponding Type 1 message and compute the difference between the two.
4. If difference is above threshold, launch the alarm.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. Im not sure what I want to do for metrics - either inside or outside AWS. But yeah, I guess that would work.